# Is HTTP response a single ASCII Encoded text file ? or the data and the headers are sent separately?

Tags: http, networking, https

So according to [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#:%7E:text=HTTP%20messages%20are%20composed%20of,and%20span%20over%20multiple%20lines), http messages are composed of textual information encoded in ASCII.

> HTTP messages are composed of textual information encoded in ASCII,
> and span over multiple lines.

So, when we request a binary file such as an Image, how is it represented in the response message?

(Assuming the response is a single text file containing both headers and data)
Is it also ASCII encoded?

If not, then are headers and data transferred separately? If yes, please share some resources where I can learn the working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTTP/1.1 (not HTTP/2 or HTTP/3), message header and control information is transferred as plain text. The actual request payloads are binary, and thus no encoding is needed.

See IERF RFCs 9110..9114.